# Conditionally calculating the difference between max(raster) and each raster layer of raster stack

Tags: r, list, max, raster

I have a list of raster stacks named `r.lst`. I need to calculate the difference between `max(r.lst[[i]])` (stacked rasters) and every raster layer of that raster stack. However, I want to do this conditionally for each pixel by considering `which.max(r.lst[[i]])`. So that each cell in deducted from its **previous** max not the next. Please see below example:

```
# example data-------------------------------------------
set.seed(123)
#our list of rasters
r.lst <- as.list(1:3)
# setting up list pf raster stacks
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = runif(36, 1, 5))
r.lst[[1]] <- stack(lapply(1:8, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
r.lst[[2]] <- stack(lapply(1:6, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
r.lst[[3]] <- stack(lapply(1:7, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
```

I can easily calculate the difference for every single layer within each three raster stack of `r.lst[[i]]` as below:

```
# compute the difference between max and min
x1 <- list()
x2 <- list()
xx <- list()

for (i in 1:length(r.lst)) {
  x1[[i]] <- max(r.lst[[i]])
  x2[[i]] <- which.max(r.lst[[i]])
  x <- list()
  for (j in 1:nlayers(r.lst[[i]])){
    x[[j]] <- x1[[i]]-r.lst[[i]][[j]]
  }
  xx[[i]] <- stack(x)
  print(i)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,4), oma=c(0,0,0,1), mai=c(0.7,0.4,0.7,0.4))
plot(r.lst[[1]][[1]], main="Input.Raster")  #Input from stack
plot(x1[[1]], main="Max")                   #Max of stack
plot(x2[[1]], main="Max.Index")             #Index of Max value in raster stack
plot(xx[[1]][[1]], main="Results")          #OUTPUT (not what I wanted)
```

[image]

But this is not what I want. I need to consider `which.max(r.lst[[i]])` in each round of calculation so that if the index of a layer under consideration is bigger than the index of `which.max(r.lst[[i]])` we calculate the difference, if not I need to calculate the difference considering earlier max layer. Simply the calculation for every raster layer is only valid compared to its earlier max not the next.

Comment: TL; DR. But my first impression is you just need one additional variable `max` that is initiated before the for-loop and increases in every iteration only if `max(r.lst[[i]]) > max`. Or is this not what you want?

Comment: @symbolrush thanks for trying to help. It's not what I want. The condition would be based on corresponding individual raster cells of `which.max(r.lst[[i]])` and `r.lst[[i]][[j]]` index itself. Simple `max(r.lst[[i]]) > max` wont really help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the below.

Example data

```
library(raster)
set.seed(123)
r <- raster(res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5)
r.lst <- list()
r.lst[[1]] <- stack(lapply(1:8, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
r.lst[[2]] <- stack(lapply(1:6, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
r.lst[[3]] <- stack(lapply(1:7, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
```

Solution

```
xx <- list()
for (i in 1:length(r.lst)) {
    xx[[i]] <- cummax( r.lst[[i]] ) -  r.lst[[i]]
}
```

That is, you can use `cummax` to get the max value of the prior values (including the current value)

```
x <- c(1:3, 3:1, 4, 3)
cummax(x)
#[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
x - cummax(x)
#[1]  0  0  0  0 -1 -2  0 -1
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I did not know about `cummax`. Why the first raster is always empty for all stacks then? I have tried to mask each `xx` from my script with `Max.Index` rasters to double-check the values and your solution works perfect. However, I am puzzled about the first raster of each stack that is always totally empty.

Comment: The first layer only has zeros because the value of the input first layer is always the same as the maximum value when only that layer is considered. No other values can be considered, as there are no earlier values (layers).